# TYPO3 Extbase hide new records on default

Tags: typo3, extbase

Created an extbase extension via Extension Builder.

When a new record is added via frontend, I want it to be disabled (hidden) by default. So an admin can have a look at it first, before publishing it.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Can't use TCAdefaults, since I only want this to happen for this one extension.

Comment: Why can't you use `TCAdefaults.tx_myext_domain_model_item.hidden = 1`?

Answer (score 4):

Add the boolean property `$hidden` to your model with its getter and setter.

You can default it to `true` in your model.

Or (if you only need it to be true in one action) before you persist your object in your repository, you can `$model->setHidden(true)`.